# JDBC Transactions

Tags: web-services, jdbc, transactions, mule

I have a flow where I need to write to 3 tables at once from a call to a web service. This will be a one way service. So the inbound is the web service and the outbound is JDBC with 3 inserts.

The tables are Parent Table and 2 child tables and they need to be written in that sequence. Do I need to use a synchronous flow in order to avoid multiple threads and what transaction should I use? I guess its simple transaction since all tables are in the same database. Will the definition below work?

```xml
<flow name="xxx" doc:name="xxx" processingStrategy="synchronous">
  <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="3366" doc:name="HTTP" />
  <transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN">
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insert" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="Insert 1">
      <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
      <jdbc:query key="insert" value="insert into Parent values (#[payload], 'Test 1')" /></jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insert2" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="Insert 2">
      <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
      <jdbc:query key="insert2" value="insert into ChildA values (#[payload + 1], 'Test 2')" /></jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insert3" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="Insert 2">
      <jdbc:transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" />
      <jdbc:query key="insert3" value="insert into ChildB values (#[payload + 1], 'Test 2')" /></jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
  </transactional>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. All endpoints participating in a transaction will inherently be synchronous.
2. Yes standard transactions are fine if they are all using the same `connector`.

You can just use:

```
    <transactional>
       <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insert" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="Insert 1">
            <jdbc:query key="insert" value="insert into Parent values (#[payload], 'Test 1')" />
       </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
       <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insert2" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="Insert 2">
            <jdbc:query key="insert2" value="insert into ChildA values (#[payload + 1], 'Test 2')" />
       </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
       <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insert3" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="dbConnector" doc:name="Insert 2">
           <jdbc:query key="insert3" value="insert into ChildB values (#[payload + 1], 'Test 2')" />
       </jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
    </transactional>
```

Mule will find the first endpoint and start a transaction for it, which the others should join

Comment: Thanks Ryan will this also facilitate the inserts are in order here insert parent has to happens first before the childs.

Comment: Yes, as they will be synchronous they will run in the order defined.